# Error: Cannot find module "ms-vscode.js-debug/src/bootloader.bundle.js" Require stack: "internal/preload"

Tags: typescript, docker, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I am running a typescript application inside dockers in vsc which I am trying to debug, the problem is after the debugger of vsc attach to the docker instance I get the following error

```
[+] Running 1/0
 ⠿ Container bot-dev  Created                                                                                                                           0.1s
Attaching to bot-dev
bot-dev  |
bot-dev  | > bot@1.0.0 bot-dev
bot-dev  | > nodemon --signal SIGINT bot/index.ts
bot-dev  |
bot-dev  | [nodemon] 2.0.21
bot-dev  | [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
bot-dev  | [nodemon] watching path(s): bot/index.ts
bot-dev  | [nodemon] watching extensions: ts
bot-dev  | [nodemon] starting `npx --node-options='--require ts-node/register -r tsconfig-paths/register  --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229' --nolazy hardhat run --network docker bot/index.ts`
bot-dev  | Debugger listening on ws://0.0.0.0:9229/ceeb98dc-c9b0-410d-9934-cfeb56eba339
bot-dev  | For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
bot-dev  | Debugger attached.
bot-dev  | node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988
bot-dev  |   throw err;
bot-dev  |   ^
bot-dev  |
bot-dev  | Error: Cannot find module '/Applications/VisualStudioCode.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/ms-vscode.js-debug/src/bootloader.bundle.js'
bot-dev  | Require stack:
bot-dev  | - internal/preload
bot-dev  |     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:15)
bot-dev  |     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:833:27)
bot-dev  |     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1051:19)
bot-dev  |     at Module._preloadModules (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1326:12)
bot-dev  |     at loadPreloadModules (node:internal/process/pre_execution:597:5)
bot-dev  |     at prepareMainThreadExecution (node:internal/process/pre_execution:104:3)
bot-dev  |     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:10:1 {
bot-dev  |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
bot-dev  |   requireStack: [ 'internal/preload' ]
bot-dev  | }
bot-dev  |
bot-dev  | Node.js v18.10.0
bot-dev  | Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
```

I run the docker instance with docker compose:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  bot-dev:
    image: node:18.10.0-alpine3.16
    container_name: bot-dev
    volumes:
      - ./../../:/app
    working_dir: /app
    ports:
      - 3000:300
      - 9229:9229
      - 8082:8545
    command:
      - /bin/sh
      - -c
      - |
        npm run bot-dev
```

My launch.json file is as follows:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Bot",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "address": "localhost",
            "port": 9229,
            "restart": true,
            "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "sourceMaps": true 
          },
    ]
}
```

The module which it complains about it exists on my local machine but I am not sure if it is trying to look for it inside my docker, if I dont run the debugger in my vsc and it does not attach to the docker it runs fine, I have tried reinstalling node_modules inside the docker image and disabling autoAttach but nothing I try seems to help

Would appreciate some help,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By default, the VS Code JS debugger is attached to any child process. When a child process is spawned inside the docker container, VS Code tries to register the debugger module from the path

```bash
/Applications/VisualStudioCode.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/ms-vscode.js-debug/src/bootloader.bundle.js
```

which doesn't exist inside the container, producing the `Cannot find module` error.

You can disable this behaviour by adding `"autoAttachChildProcesses": false` to your `launch.json` config.

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Bot",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "address": "localhost",
            "port": 9229,
            "restart": true,
            "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "autoAttachChildProcesses": false
          },
    ]
}
```

See [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/blob/main/OPTIONS.md) for all the available `launch.json` options for the JS debugger.